# Jekyll + AngularJS: any way to force "raw" in YAML?

Tags: angularjs, github, jekyll

Pretty new to Jekyll (for github), I'm looking if there is a way to force raw in YAML header.

I'm using this HTML layout (called snippets)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
  ...
</head>
{{content}}
</html>
```

I have a few HTML content which uses it this way:

```
---
layout: snippets
---
{% raw %}
<body>
  ....
</body>
{% endraw %}
```

Because they provide AngularJS code, I have to enclosed it in raw/endraw block.
Is there a way to set the file content as raw directly in the header, kinda:

```
---
layout: snippets
raw: true
---
<body>
  ....
</body>
```

Comment: No way to do this without a generator plugin. But if you target github pages. It's no no.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought